# Polyglossia resets font (Lucida, lucimatx)?

Tags: fonts, polyglossia

I'm running into a problem when loading polyglossia with the Lucida fonts that I bought from pctex.com. I compile with Xelatex.

```
\usepackage[romanfamily=bright]{lucimatx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
```

For some reason polyglossia always seems to reset the font to the standard latex font. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `polyglossia` package needs `fontspec`, but the Lucida fonts you have are only in T1 encoding, while the encoding required for using `fontspec` is EU1 (EU2 when LuaLaTeX is used).

Thus loading the two packages in that order overrides the font selections made by `lucimatx`, because `fontspec` does its own.

You could change the loading order:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % load fontspec
\let\hbar\undefined % to avoid an error message
\usepackage[romanfamily=bright]{lucimatx}
\AtBeginDocument{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont} % set the font encoding

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

I don't think you gain anything with this. My suggestion is to use `pdflatex` and `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[romanfamily=bright]{lucimatx}

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Actually `babel` for English only is not required.

Comment: You first workaround indeed does not work. Somwhere I read that one should use polyglossia with Xelatex? In fact babel seems to work as well. For some reason I used polyglossia but can't remember exactly why right now.